# how can we fill the multiple textboxes from the selectbox value change through AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to fill my all textboxes and dynamic table by `onchange` event of selectbox through AJAX in PHP and HTML.
i have done something on it But this AJAX function only return one value from the database file.
This is Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function fetch_select(val)
     {
         $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                 url: 'dbassign.php',
                 data: {
                           get_option:val
                       },
                 success: function (response) {

              $('#cust').val(response);
         }
   });
}
```

This is for selectbox `onchange` event

```
<select name='cminvoice' onchange='fetch_select(this.value)' class='form-control' autofocus>
```

and this is my database file

```
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
     $state = $_POST['get_option'];
     $find=mysql_query("select custn from tbbill where invoice=$state");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
     {
       echo "$row[custn]";

     }
}
```

I have applied this same function on multiple valuebut it show all data in same textboxes.

Comment: "I have applied this same function on multiple value but it show all data in same textboxes." - this is because you are appending response every time to same textbox `$('#cust').val(response);`

Comment: you will have to specify separately each textbox for response. Either you can pass the expected textbox's id as parameter to function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use JSON_encode to do this task which make requests easy to handle.

after geting the result from server in .php file try to make something simple like this

```
 $data = array("for_box_one"=>'value1',"for_box_two"=>'value2');
 echo json_encode($data);
 die;
```

also change

```
    success: function (response) {
          $('#cust').val(response);
     }
```

to

```
     success: function (response) {
          $('#cust').val(response.for_box_one);
          // rest will be same 
          $('#cust2').val(response.for_box_two);
          // as so on whatever you want 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to include jquery.js
try this code
create table as follow

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbbill` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `custn` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `invoice` varchar(25) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  --
  -- Dumping data for table `tbbill`
  --

INSERT INTO `tbbill` (`id`, `custn`, `invoice`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', 'Value1'),
(2, 'xyz', 'Value1'),
(3, 'pqr', 'Value1'),
(4, 'qwe', 'Value1');
```

page1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch_select(val)
 { alert(val);
     $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: 'dbassign.php',
             data: {
                       get_option:val
                   },
             success: function (response) {
            response=response.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
            console.log(response);
            response=response.split(","); 
            var i=0;
            $.each(response, function(key, val) {
                i++;
                if(val!=""){
                    $(".response_elements").append("<input type='text' 
name='custn"+i+"' value='"+val+"'/><br/>");     
                }

            });
       }
   });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name='cminvoice' onchange='fetch_select(this.value)' class='form-
control' autofocus>
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="Value1">Value1</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
</select>
<div class="response_elements">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

dbassign.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{
     $state = $_POST['get_option'];
     $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
     mysql_select_db('db_wtg');
     $find=mysql_query("select custn from tbbill where     
     invoice='".$state."'");
     $data="";
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
     {
       $data.=$row['custn'].",";
     }
    echo $data;
}

?>
```